# Elasticsearch - What will range filter use without specifying 'execution'

Tags: elasticsearch

In the Elasticsearch documentation, it mentions that I can set an `exeuction` property on a range filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html#_execution

If I don't specify the value, will it use `index` or `fielddata` by default or neither?

Likewise, if it uses `index` by default, is it also caching by default?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html#_caching_16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the `execution` mode for a `range` filter, it will use `index` by default (the value [is hardcoded](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/RangeFilterParser.java#L69) in the source code).

From there on, it logically follows that caching will be enabled by default as can be seen a bit further [in the code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/RangeFilterParser.java#L136).

When the documentation doesn't tell, the source code will ;)